# Wrong calculation

Tags: php, math

I got a weird problem.

I want a simple system which shows an error if there are more than 1 request in one second.

What i did:

```
        if(!isset($_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_time']) || $_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_time'] = null) {
        $_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_time'] = microtime(true);
        $_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_request'] = 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_request'] += 1;
        if($_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_request'] >= 2 && microtime(true) - $_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_time'] < 1) {
            die('Too many requests!');
        } elseif(microtime(true) - $_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_time'] > 1) {
            # Reset the counter since more than a second is over
            $_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_time'] = null;
        }
```

I have no clue what i did wrong, i guess the solution is pretty easy (maybe just a calculation error.. it's already 3 AM here).

Comment: are you trying to store a "global" request counter in a session? but sessions are per client... or is it requests per second per client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `if` statement isn't valid.

```
$time = $_SESSION['protect']['mass_request_time'];
if (!isset($time) || $time = null)
```

Your code just just sets the time to `null`. Use `==` instead.